# rvm gemsets with Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, rvmrc

### Using Rails:

If Bundler retrieves the proper gems (and dependencies) and locks them in the Gemfile.lock for a given project, isn't using a gemset for this same project overkill? I've been told that using gemsets is still a good practice because merely having 2 versions of the same gem in your current PATH can cause conflicts. Is this right, or do you only need one or the other: Bundler or RVM?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's redundant to use RVM's gemsets if you're using bundler.

Conflicts when using Bundler arise primarily for two reason:

1. Using gems that require other gems without precise version specifications.
2. Executable conflicts: you have both rails v3 and v4 installed, so where do we go to when calling `rails g migration` or calling `rake`?

The first issue can be resolved if you're careful about specifying your gem versions more explicitly in your Gemfile.

When working within a project with a Gemfile, the second issue can be resolved by prefixing executable calls with `bundle exec`, which will run the command within the context of the current bundle (e.g. `bundle exec rake db:migrate`).

When you want to specify a gem version outside of a Gemfile's context (e.g. `rails new fancy_app`), you can specify any gem's version by providing it as the first argument surrounded by underscores.

```
rake --version
rake _10.3.1_ --version
rails new rails_latest_app
rails _3.2.12_ new rails_3_app
rails _4.0.4_ new rails_4_app
```

RubyGems handles all of this for you by creating version-aware wrappers for any gem's executables. Just run `` cat `which gem_executable` `` (with `gem_executable` being something like `rake`, `rails`, `foreman`, `pry`, etc.) and have a look.

Stephen Ball has a good blog post about [how to use Bundler instead of RVM gemsets](http://rakeroutes.com/blog/how-to-use-bundler-instead-of-rvm-gemsets/), which explores the overlaps in further detail.

While RVM's gemsets are not necessary, RVM provides other conveniences:

- Automatically adding bundler binstubs to the `PATH`, so you can avoid typing `bundle exec`. Note the [bundler plugin for `oh-my-zsh`](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/blob/master/plugins/bundler/bundler.plugin.zsh) provides the same feature
- Managing multiple Ruby versions

The ruby version manager `rbenv` provides similar features as well.

Comment: Wow, this was a perfect answer. "bundle exec" makes more sense now in tutorials as well. Thanks! I'd up vote but apparently I don't have enough rep points haha

Answer (score 2):

Yes, gemsets are overkill. Just use bundler.

RVM is still usefull for managing versions of Ruby itself - but don't use it for gemsets. Just use bundler for gem version management.

Regarding conflicts between gem versions, if you use `bundle exec` before each command you shouldn't have a problem - eg. `bundle exec rake db:migrate` or whatever.

Comment: I'd up vote but apparently I don't have enough rep points, thanks anyways